# Is there any way for a time picker to have infinite scroll?

Tags: codenameone

The existing cn1 picker has start time and end time. Before start time and after the end time - the picker space is empty, but it still scrolls and looks a bit off.

Is it possible to make a picker have an infinite scroll of numbers? From 1 to 12, and 00 to 59 for example. This is a question specifically for Picker implementation on iOS.

See the attached screenshot on what I mean. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: @Luuk please see that this is a question related specifically to codenameone framework.

Answer (score 1):

We tried to mirror the iOS native picker which has that same limitation I think this would be a bit challenging to implement since the picker doesn't rely on `List` which already has this feature.

Any way to workaround this would require changes to the API and the implementation here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/spinner/Spinner3D.java